# background change in Chrome when mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I use Chrome, background = CSS3

```
<h4 class="title-name clearfix"><a href="****************">Fairy Tail - LUCY</a>            </h4>
```

why when i hover mouse over title, background change , it happen only in Chrome.
[image]

**Edit:** I found out solve, If `title-name{padding: 7px 15px}` then must change `title-name a{padding:7px 15px}` 'll fixed in Chrome change background when mouse hover

Comment: Are you able to post a demo anywhere, such as [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem? And, maybe post the relevant css here?

Comment: If it is hosted on a website then please point us to it. I will have a butchers for you.

Comment: Voting to close this question, since it's incomplete, vague and unanswerable in it's current form. Please try to update it with some information that may actually help us pinpoint your problem.

Comment: about this, i cant to reproduce error because it only happen on my site and CHrome, if i remake on JSbind or JS Fiddle it dont happen ( i dont understand why ). And my site is secret i cant show anybody

Comment: If it happens only on your website and not on js fiddle, with the same code/browser, I might say that there's another CSS command involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really give enough information, as the commenters have mentioned. 
I think you are trying to select it incorrectly in the css. Your css selector should be as follows:

```
.title-name a {
background: red;
}
.title-name a:hover {
background: white;
}
```